# How to update a record in Azure Mobile Service ScheduledJob (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, azure-mobile-services

I have a .NET backend Mobile Service ScheduledJob.  How can I update a record in the database from the ScheduledJob class?  I found a MSDN example of inserting using the dbcontext, but there doesn't seem to be an update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you've seen the use of InsertAsync? Have you tried using UpdateAsync, the equivalent method for update?

Link to MSDN doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn654843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In ScheduledJob you should not use the services/controller for it or http request for use services/controller, because it not make sense.

For that you want, you need to create the object that represent the dbContext, this way you can do all operation to the database and at the end do a save changes.